# padding so that top header bar does not block text

Tags: html, css

I have a header bar with many links that floats at the top of the page even when scrolled down. When I click on these links, it links to a place further down on the page. My problem is that when I click on the link, it links to the proper section, but because the bar is there, it covers part of the text I would like the user to see. For example, clicking on "About" brings me to the About section, but the top bar blocks the words about. Is there a way to pad each section when it is linked to by the top bar?

Comment: have you tried adding a padding top to your sections? `section { padding-top: 30px; }` or whatever the padding is. You can check how it works here [twitter bootstrap base css](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at those SO questions:

[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)
[Sticky Header Covers Anchor Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660132/sticky-header-covers-anchor-text)

Some solutions:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/